# angular 4 : Can't bind to 'ngForFor' since it isn't a known property of 'li'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angularjs-ng-repeat, ngfor

I've just started learning angular 4. This is a simple code that I'm trying to implement in Visual Studio Code, but keep getting this error.

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngForFor' since it isn't a known property of 'li'. ("
</ul>
<ul>
 <li [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let hobby for hobbies">{{hobby}}</li>
</ul>"): ng:///AppModule/UserComponent.html@6:6
Property binding ngForFor not used by any directive on an embedded template. 
Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are 
listed in the "@NgModule.declarations".("
</ul>
<ul>
[ERROR ->]<li *ngFor="let hobby for hobbies">{{hobby}}</li>
</ul>"): ng:///AppModule/UserComponent.html@6:2
```

I tried previous solutions of adding the CommonModule to the app.module file. But it hasn't solved  the issue.I cannot figure out what is wrong.

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

}
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { UserComponent } from './components/user/user.component';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    UserComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,CommonModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

user.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-user',
  templateUrl: './user.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user.component.css']
})
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {
  name:string;
  age:number;
  address: Address;
  hobbies:string[];


  constructor() { 
    console.log('constructor ran ...');
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  console.log('ngOnInit ran ...');
  this.name='Raul';
  this.age=22;
  this.address= {
    street:'abc',
    city:'xyz',
    country: 'jkl'
  }
  this.hobbies=['reading','playing','swimming'];
  }

}

interface Address{
  street:string,
  city:string,
  country:string

}
```

user.component.html:

```
<h1>{{name}}</h1>
<ul>
  <li>Age:{{age}}</li>
  <li>Address:{{address.street}}, {{address.city}},{{address.country}}</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let hobby for hobbies">{{hobby}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: 'let hobby of hobbies' instead of 'let hobby for hobbies'

Comment: thanks alot, that was helpful!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

should be `of` instead of `for` inside the `ngFor`

```
ngFor="let hobby of hobbies"
```

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174389/should-we-answer-or-comment-on-a-typo-question